# Find all the bases for given reference position

Tags: sam, pysam

Hi im looking for the aligned bases in the reads for a given reference position. im using the following script from the pysam documentataion.
I adjusted it to find the specified position. in this case 24793.

```
import pysam

samfile = pysam.AlignmentFile("generated_alignment_sorted.bam", "rb" )
for pileupcolumn in samfile.pileup("chr05_modified.copy0", 10, 52000000):
    if pileupcolumn.pos == 24793:
        print ("\ncoverage at base %s = %s" %
               (pileupcolumn.pos, pileupcolumn.n))
        for pileupread in pileupcolumn.pileups:
                print ('\tbase in read %s = %s' %
                      (pileupread.alignment.query_name.split(';')[0],
                       pileupread.alignment.query_sequence[pileupread.query_position]))

samfile.close()
```

This outputs:

```
coverage at base 24793 = 6
        base in read m419941/6207/CCS Read=419941 = C
```

For all the position I tried it doesnt print out the same number of bases as it says that the coverage is.
shouldnt this print out 6 times: base in read m419941/6207/CCS Read=419941 = C for different reads?

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pileupcolumn.n` shows the total number of the reads that cover this basepair (in this case 24793). However, `pileupcolumn.pileups` iterates over the reads that cover this base pair AND this base pair has a minimum quality in those reads. So it has an additional filter for the reads to be considered. You can modify the quality threshold by setting `min_base_quality` parameter when you call pileup.

To have a similar filter applied to both coverage and reads, you can use `piliecolumn.get_num_aligned()` to get the number of segments and `pileupcolumn.pileups` to get the segments themselves.